Use fourier transform to compute an integral
For $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ I'm asked to solve the integral $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos bt}{t^2+a^2}dt$$
I'm a bit lost on how to do this. I think I should find a function such that it's fourier transform is something like the integrand and then using something like plancherel to actually compute the integral but I'm having trouble doing so. Any help would be appreciated.

write $\cos (bt)$ using exponentials and then use the properies of Fourier transform. See for example this answer, or this one.

You can as well use the residue method. WLOG we may assume $b\ge 0$. Then calculate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {e^{ibt}\over t^2+a^2},dt$ applying the integrals over the upper half circles.

The fact that the integrand is even and a simple change of variable gives
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(bt)}{t^2+a^2}\,\mathrm d t = \frac{1}{2|a|}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos(abt)}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm d t
\\
= \frac{1}{2|a|}\, \mathrm{Re}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-iabt}}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm d t\right) = \frac{1}{2|a|}\,\mathrm{Re}\mathcal{F}\left(\frac{1}{1+t^2}\right)(ab)
$$

Is there an easy way to compute $ReF(\frac{1}{1+t^2}) (ab)$ without using residue theorem?

@H4z3 What is the inverse Fourier transform of $e^{-|\omega|}$?

I got that it's $-2\frac{1}{1+w^2}$ (I think the $-2$ is because i'm taking the transform as $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-iwx}dx$ without the $2\pi$ factor) So if $g(t) = e^{|t|}$ then we get that $F(f)(w) = -2F(F^{-1})(g)(w) = -2g(w)$, is this correct?

I just realized i had a minus sign wrong and was missing a $\pi$ factor, so the integral is $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos(bt)}{t^2+a^2} = \frac{\pi}{a}e^{-|ab|}$, is this right?
